# Problem with autocorrelation in linear regression

Tags: regression, econometrics, autocorrelation

I have a linear model: `acc2014 = v + b*acc2013 + cbook2013`. The independent variables are economic variables. The error terms are correlated. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: Besides the suggestion given below, as reference chapter 8 from [Mostly Harmless Econometrics](http://www.mostlyharmlesseconometrics.com/) might be worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use a dynamic regression model with ARIMA errors. Rob Hyndman's [online book](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/9/1) has an excellent introduction and some examples.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a best solution in general, it depends on your case. For example:

- including lags of the dependent/indepedented variable/s can be a good solution to take into account autocorrelation in your model
- if your goal is to analyze the coefficients you can use heteroscedasticity-consistent standard errors
- otherwise as suggested you can change the underlying model of residuals